# Ordering a list of lists by lists len

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to order a list of lists by `len` size. But I'm getting a weird syntax error. I'm new to python so I'm probably doing something wrong

Relevant part of the code:

```
 orderedpaths=[]
 if(len(paths)==1):
  orderedpaths=paths
 else: 
  c=0
  while(len(paths)!=0):

   if(c==0):
    smallest=(len(paths[c])
    c+=1

   else:
    if(len[paths[c])<smallest):
     smallest=(len(paths[c]))
     orderedpaths.append(paths[c])
     del paths[c]
     c+=1    

 return orderedpaths
```

the error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 153
    c+=1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: Don't parenthesize your if-conditions, Python doesn't need it and it just adds visual noise.

Comment: you might want to read [PEP 8, Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), specifically about indentation, whitespace, and boolean comparisons. But more importantly, *definitely* use Python's built-in `sorted()` or `list.sort()` functions, as they much faster than O(n^2), which I'm pretty sure your method will be, because `del paths[c]` is not constant time.

Answer (score 22):

Your problem was the number of brackets in:

```
smallest=(len(paths[c])
```

and in:

```
if(len[paths[c])<smallest):
```

and also in:

```
if(len[paths[c])<smallest):
```

To sort paths according to their length, you can try this:

```
orderedpaths = sorted(paths, key=len)
```

Here's the documentation for [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: These Python questions are like a race. The speed is measured in tens of seconds. `:)`

Comment: If you actually want to sort `paths` and not make a sorted copy, you would do `paths.sort(key=len)`

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [eumiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735704/ordering-a-list-of-lists-by-lists-len/4735737#4735737) using [sorted()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) is the way to go.

Note that `sorted()` (as well as `list.sort(key=..)`) was only introduced in Python 2.4. If you're in my boat and have to make do with <2.4, you could create your own version. Rough example:

```
import inspect
def my_sorted(in_list, key=lambda x:x):

    # basic error checking
    if not is_instance(in_list, list):
        raise ValueError("expecting 1st argument to be a list")

    if not inspect.isroutine(key):
        raise ValueError("key must be a function/method")

    # convert to [ (key(item1), item1), .... ]
    key_map = map(lambda x: (key(x),x), in_list)
    # standard sort, while effectively sort by key(item)
    key_map.sort()

    # convert back original format and return
    return [x for _,x in key_map]
```

You can then use it as such:

```
orderedpaths = my_sorted(paths, key=len)
```

Comment: That's supposed to be orderedpaths = my_sorted(paths, key=len) I guess

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this pretty piece of code :) :

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1,2]]
>>> b = sorted(a, lambda x,y: 1 if len(x)>len(y) else -1 if len(x)<len(y) else 0)
>>> print b
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

and swap 1 with -1 if you want another sorting order.

As commenters notice this code works only in python 2.x.
There is some prettier code which works in python 3.x as well:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1,2]]
>>> b = sorted(a, key = len)
>>> print b
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: `sorted(a, key=len)` is prettier. `;)`

Comment: @ikostia: why did you post it then?

Comment: @SilentGhost: the one not working on my python 2.6.6 is not my answer but ulidtko's comment.

Comment: Don't fool people, `sorted(a, key=len)` is working, both in Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: you're not able to see ulidtko's answer. eumiro's answer is working perfectly fine on python2.6